# Crash without Override, error with it in a onClick event

Tags: java, android, onclick

My activity crashes when I try to make run it, this is the code :

```
public class WifiActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listeViewWifi;
    private List<WifiItem> listeWifiItem;
    private WifiAdapter wifiAdapter;
    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    private WifiBroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
    private Timer timer;
    private Timer timer2;
    private boolean success;
    private boolean broadcastFinish;
    private Button buttonMeasure;
    private Button buttonLocate;
    private EditText coordX;
    private EditText coordY;
    private float[][][] radioMap = new float[100][100][5];


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_wifi);
       listeViewWifi = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewWifi);
           wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

               if(wifiManager != null){
                   wifiManager.startScan();}

                       // On récupère le service WiFi d'Android
                       wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

                       // Gestion de la liste des AP WiFi (voir tuto sur les adapters et les
                       // listviews)
                       listeWifiItem = new ArrayList<WifiItem>();
                       wifiAdapter = new WifiAdapter(this, listeWifiItem);
                       listeViewWifi.setAdapter(wifiAdapter);

                       // Création du broadcast Receiver
                       broadcastReceiver = new WifiBroadcastReceiver();

                       // On attache le receiver au scan result
                       registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
                      /* timer = new Timer(this);
                       timer.applyTimer();*/

                       buttonLocate = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonLocate);
                       buttonMeasure = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonMeasure);

                       buttonMeasure.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
                       buttonLocate.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    }

    // @Override //Error if I write it,  and there is a crash if I delete it.
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonMeasure:

       coordX = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.coordX);
       coordY = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.coordY);

       String xString = coordX.getText().toString();
       final int xInt = Integer.parseInt(xString);

       String yString = coordY.getText().toString();
       final int yInt = Integer.parseInt(yString);

       timer2 = new Timer(WifiActivity.this);

       while(broadcastReceiver.getMeasureFinished()<=49){
           Log.d("info7","mesure" + broadcastReceiver.getMeasureFinished());

           timer2.applyTimer();
       }

       for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
           radioMap[xInt][yInt][i]=broadcastReceiver.getRSSI(i);
       }

        case R.id.buttonLocate:
            //localization.
        }
   }
```

What is the problem? Why can I not write @Override on the OnClick event? How can I solve it? I tried to do without the override but the program crashes and if I write it eclipse is complaining that there is an error... So I don't know how can I proceed...

Thanks!

Comment: you don't declare that you implement onClickListener ...

Comment: Ok thanks! It is a beginner error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `WifiActivity` so it implements `OnClickListener`:

```
public class WifiActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```